# Call Eventhandler from ClientSide JS

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I was looking at this post by Jeremy Hodge
http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC 
With Event handlers and calling them from ClientSide JS.
But I can get them to work if I put some SSJS in side the event I would like to fire.

Does this still work or am I doing something wrong?

```
    <xp:button value="click me" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[executeOnServer('dostuff');]]></xp:this.script>

        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onfubar" id="dostuff" submit="true">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("1");viewScope.data="Y"}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

The executeOnServer function comes directly from Jeremys page

Comment: don't you need to executeOnServer("#{id:dostuff}") ?

Comment: @Fredrik: I have created a blank XPage, added the function and your code above. It works as designed ("1" was printed to server console) with 8.5.3.

Comment: I've checked again and it works if you place it directly inside an XPage but If you place it inside a Custom Control nothing happends.
So there is my real problem.

Comment: Working link for the Jeremy Hodge post: http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem my it wasn't in my code but in the Executeonserver code.
Thanks everybody for the help to get the solution.

this line needed to change
   dojo.query('[name="$$xspsubmitid"]')[0].value =  form.id + ':' +functionName;

to

dojo.query('[name="$$xspsubmitid"]')[0].value = functionName;

Of course when you have the answer everything seams easy.

Answer (score 4):

If the event is contained in a custom control the event is a child of the custom control and has another id then in an event in the XPage.

The id of the event in a normal XPage:

```
view:_id1:dostuff
```

If it is contained by a custom control:

```
view:_id1:_id5:dostuff
```

where **_id5** is the id of the custom control.

This is not working with the current CSJS code.

To fix this, you can add add an id to your custom control

```
 <xc:event id="abc"></xc:event>
```

and then calculate the id of the custom control and add it to the event:

```
<xp:button value="click meCC" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false"
        refreshMode="none">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        var ccId = '#{javascript:getComponent('abc').getId()}';
         executeOnServer(ccId + ':dostuff');]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Hope this helps

Sven

Comment: You can also use getComponent('dostuff').getClientId(facesContext) to calculate the id of the event.

Answer (score 1):

First, for the "click me" button the "Server Options" should be set to "No Submission" (remove refreshMode="complete" and set submit="false"). Which means it only executes the client script (in this case running the "dostuff" event). Second the "submit" parameter from the "dostuff" eventHandler should be set to "false".

The code below will print "1" in the server Console when clicking the "click me" button. Hope this helps.

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/executeOnServer.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>

<xp:button value="click me" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[executeOnServer("dostuff");]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>

<xp:eventHandler event="onfubar" id="dostuff" submit="false">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("1");}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but I largely prefer the Remote Service control from the Extension library (xe:jsonRpcService).

Comment: What I see is the major problem with the Remote Service Control is that it doesn't operate in the same viewScope as the rest of the page.

Comment: :-O  Ah, could be, I didn't know; but sessionScope should be okay.

Answer (score -1):

Jeremy Hodge has wrote a terrific blog article about this subject.
http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=88065536729EA065852578CB0066ADEC

An eventhandler can exist without a surrounding button, give the eventhandler an id and you can access it.

Comment: Sorry Frank but that is the article I'm refering to.