# executeonServer from a customcontrol - how caputer Id from current CC

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Ho to all,
I have a little problem..my code work very well..if I have my event handler into a XPages

```
`<xp:eventHandler event="autoSaveEvent" id="autoSaveDoc"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:saveDocument>
    </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>`
```

but If I insert this into a Custom Control...the **executeonserver** don't work...
I have read from here [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721422/call-eventhandler-from-clientside-js) but for work I need to capture the id of my Custom Control..someone have any suggest?

Comment: Can you show the code of your custom control? Are there any errors displayed in your console? ( display by hitting f12)

Comment: sorry i have insert below my updated question. Tnx you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the customcontrol you could probably do something like this.
where abc is the name of a top level component in the custom control.

var ccId = '#{javascript:getComponent('abc').getParent().getId()}';

Answer (score 0):

Tnx you @Fredrik Norling this is very good suggest!

this code below code work in every tree of child of where you insert the CC:

```
var eventId="#{javascript:getClientId('autoSaveDoc')}"
var n=eventId.split("view:_id1:"); 
var ccId=n[1];
```